# A counter example to "Banachness"

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

We know that if $V_2$ is a Banach Space then $\mathcal{L}(V_1,V_2)$ is also a Banach space, but can we state the converse? That is, does $\mathcal{L}(V_1,V_2)$ being a Banach Space implies that$V_2$ is a Banach Space (if $V_1\neq \{0\}$)?

I think the answer is no but im no sure. I'm trying to find a counter example:

Consider a Cauchy sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q})$. We know that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't Banach cause we can make a rational sequence converge to a irrational number. But considering a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete we know that there exists a $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$||x_n-x||<\epsilon$$ Since for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n$ is bounded (hence continuous) we have $$||A_n(x_n)-A_n(x)||<\epsilon$$
And here is where i'm stuck because i cannot conclude that exists $A$ such that $$||A_n-A||<\epsilon$$

Comment: You can identify $V_2$ with a closed subspace of $\mathcal L(V_1,V_2)$. Fix any linear functional $f \colon V_1 \to \mathbb R$ with norm one, and consider the  isometry $$V_2 \ni  y \mapsto T_y \in \mathcal L(V_1,V_2)  ,$$
where $T_y(x)= f(x)y, \ x \in V_1.$

Comment: Note that $\mathcal L(\Bbb R, \Bbb Q)=\{0\}$ since constant maps are the only continuous maps from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$. Hence this is a complete $\Bbb Q$-vectorspace. The problem is however, that $\Bbb Q$ is not a complete field and doing Banach space theory where the base field is not complete is not usual, useful, interesting, or nice. In the event that the base-field is complete you have that $\mathcal L(X,Y)$ complete implies $Y$ is complete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Completeness of $\mathcal L (V_1,V_2)$ does imply completeness of $V_2$ if $V_1 \neq \{0\}$: fix any $x_0 \neq 0$ in $V_1$. There exists a continuous linear functional $f$ on $V_1$ such that $f(x_0)=1$. Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $V_2$ and let $T_nx=f(x)y_n$. Then $\|T_n-T_m\|\leq \|f\|\|y_n-y_m\| \to 0$. Hence, $T_n$ converges to some element $T$ of $\mathcal L (V_1,V_2)$. Now $T_nx_0 \to Tx_0$ which means $f(x_0)y_n \to Tx_0$. It follows that $y_n$ converges to $\frac 1 {f(x_0)} Tx_0$.

Comment: @riemannfanboy I have proved that every Cauchy sequence  $(y_n)$ in $V_2$ is convergent. Isn't that not what completeness means?

Comment: I have another question. When you say $T_n x = f(x) y_n$ aren't you assuming that $T_n$ is surjective?

Comment: No, $T_n$ is not surjective. In fact, each $T_n$ is a rank one operator with its range contained in the one-dimensional space spanned by $y_n$.  @riemannfanboy